# python normalized path gets reset in a for loop

Tags: python, string

I am trying to get a normalized path on windows. The paths are stored in a list and i am looping over those as follows:

```
>>> lst = ['C:\\', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Program Files']
>>> lst
['C:\\', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Program Files']
>>> for pth in lst:
...    print pth
...
C:\
C:\Windows
C:\Program Files
```

Notice that it has removed one backslash from the output C:\ should be C:\.

The output doesn't change even when I normalize the path in the loop as below:

```
>>> import os
>>> for pth in lst:
...     print os.path.normpath(pth)
...
C:\
C:\Windows
C:\Program Files
```

Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks

***Update***

seems like the suggestions about the raw string is a better way to handle this. But how to specify the string as a raw string within a for loop.  Example:

```
for pth in lst:
    raw_str = rpth
```

Obviously the above doesn't work . How do I achieve this? r'path/to/file' ?

Answer (score 3):

The double slash is simply string escaping - you need to escape slashes in string literals. Printing `lst[0]` before the loop will print it without the slash. If you want to really include a double slash in your literal, use the raw string syntax:

```
>>> lst = ['C:\\', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Program Files']
>>> lst[0]
'C:\\'
>>> print lst[0]
C:\
>>> lst2 = [r'C:\\', r'C:\\Windows', r'C:\\Program Files']
>>> lst2[0]
'C:\\\\'
>>> print lst2[0]
C:\\
```

**EDIT:** If you *want* to double the slashes, you can do a simple string replace:

```
>>> x = 'C:\\Windows'
>>> print x
C:\Windows
>>> x = x.replace('\\', '\\\\')
>>> print x
C:\\Windows
```

Comment: how do I create a raw string within the list? e.g. for l in lst: r = raw_string from l?

Comment: A raw string is simply a way to represent a string literal. There's no difference between it and a normal string after it is evaluated. If you explain what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to help you with that though.

Comment: hi Mark, I have updated my question to explain what I need thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Python, when you say

```
>>> s = 'C:\\'
```

`s` contains three characters: `C`, `:` and `\`.  This can be easily seen by:

```
>>> len(s)
3
```

In Python, as in many other languages, a backslash is used to escape certain characters.  For example, a newline is `\n`, a character with value `0` is `\x00`, etc.  A "real" backslash is `\\`.  So, to actually get two backslashes, you need to escape both, giving:

```
>>> s = 'C:\\\\'
```

But, Windows is perfectly happy with `/` as the separator, so you can do:

```
>>> s = 'C:/'
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\` is an escape sequence which prints `\` as the output. If you want to print `C:\\`, you'll have to use `C:\\\\` as the input string(or use raw strings ...). I can't see why you would want that. Although if you particularly want to, there are different options available.

Comment: I want it... because this path is then sent to another application (in the for loop I call another app)

Answer (score 0):

you need `\\`? you can use `print repr(pth)`

Comment: thanks RC.. I got it working with repr(pth)... but that piece of code looks ugly and need a better alternative: pth1 = repr(pth) ..pth1 looks like "'C:\\'" ... pth2 = pth[1:-1] .. to get rid of single quotes from pth1!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to use [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) for creating your windows path. You don't have to meddle with slashes as much.

eg

```
from os.path import join
rootdir="C:\\"
path1 = join(rootdir,"windows")
path2 = join(rootdir,"Program Files")
lst = [ rootdir , path1, path2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use / for sanity on windows (most programs work with both forms of slashes), but failing that, use r'' whenever you are dealing with backslashed path names.

```
r'C:\My\Windows\Path'
```

If you really want double backslashes, then that works too:

```
r'C:\\My\\Escaped\\Path'
```

Comment: yes.. raw string is the answer here.. but how do I create it within the loop?  for l in lst: l1 = raw string using l  ??